# How to express "There is a specified symbol in the following unknown numbers of characters" in regex?

Tags: regular-expression

I have many python code examples in my markdown files, which should be prepended with `>>>` symbols.

So I write a vim function to do this job:

```
function AddShellPrompt() range
    let lnum = a:firstline
    while lnum <= a:lastline
        let replaced_line = substitute(getline(lnum), '^\s\+', '&>>>', '')
        call setline(lnum, replaced_line)
        let lnum += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

The problem is, for raw text like:

```
pow(2, 3)
8
```

I need only add `>>>` before `pow(2, 3)`, but not before `8`.
So I need to expand my regex.
It comes to me that if I only add `>>>` for a line which contains any character of `+-*/%(=`.
I can get a pretty good result(though not perfect).

But the problem is, how to write regex (especially in vim) which expresses *Some of the characters in the given set has appeared in the current line?*

A specific version of this question is:
How to detect if a line contains any `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `(`, `=`, or even a word `import` with a vim regex?

---

After the suggestion of the following answers, I got my improved function as below:

```
" Massively add python prompt symbol in a markdown file
function AddShellPrompt() range
    let lnum = a:firstline
    let match_pattern = '^\s\+.*[-\+_*/%=]\|.*import\|.*print\|.*def\|.*class\|.*while\|.*for\|.*if\|.*elif\|.*else\|.*pass\|.*continue\|.*break\|.*return'
    while lnum <= a:lastline
        let current_line = getline(lnum)
        if match(current_line, match_pattern) == 0
            let replaced_line = substitute(current_line, '^\s\+', '&>>>', '')
            call setline(lnum, replaced_line)
        endif
        let lnum += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: Rather than use the function to do this, you could use `:global` with the pattern and the command `norm I>>>`. The whole command would be `:g/[-+*/%()]\|import/norm I>>>`.

Comment: @SakariCajanus, That sounds good, but I need something that I can reuse easily.

Comment: The first thought I had when reading your question was that all you need is a global substitution. Similar to Sakari's approach but without vim's specific *norm*, e.g.: `:g/[-+*/%()]\|import/s/^/>>>/`. (And yes, you can reuse that command as well, you don't need a complex function.)

Answer (score 2):

The question seems easier when you word it differently. If you are happy with the logic of *Any of the characters `-+*/%(=`or the word `import`*, the regex is simply

```
[-+*/%()]\|import
```

where
`[-+*/%()]` is a set of characters that can match, `\|` stands for *or*, and `import` is the word itself.

Of course, if you want to use that with substitute you want to match the beginning of line of the line containing the pattern, e.g.

```
^\ze.*[-+*/%()]\|import\@>
```

which adds the start-of-line, \ze to set the end of match directly after, then any characters followed by the match described before.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by including the `\|` operator in your regex.

For example :

The text :

```
sit totam impedit+ .
adipisicing eos = nulla.
sit (veniam magnam.
elit %debitis porro!
```

And the search regex :

```
/+\|=\|(\|%
```

And the regex matches the 4 lines, though it's not some valid python statement, it answers you question.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/680031/2558252